# How to call jQuery function when checkbox is checked by PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php if (isset($mod['display']) && ($mod['display'] == "1")) { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } ?>
```

jQuery:

```
function checkbox_click(current) {
  if($(current).is(':checked')) {
          // do stuff....
  } else {
          // do stuff....
  }
}
```

In the above code, when `$mod['display']` is true, the checkbox is checked but it does not invoke `checkbox_click()` function. I tried `onchange=` instead of `onclick=` but it does not seem to have any effect. I need to keep the `onclick` or `onchange` in the  field.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `prop` function for this,
Also you don't need to call function, you can create it by using `jquery.on()` function like,

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.display_checkbox',function(){
      if($(this).prop('checked')) {
              // do stuff....
      } else {
              // do stuff....
      }
   });
});
```

And then remove `onclick="checkbox_click(this);"` from your `html checkbox element`

**Updated**

To initialize it on `document ready`

```
$(function(){
   $('.display_checkbox').each(function(){
      if($(this).prop('checked')) {
              // do stuff....
      } else {
              // do stuff....
      }
   });
});
```

Read [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

Comment: No, it's still not working for my purpose. It's doing the same thing as with my original function. When checkbox is checked by PHP, it is not invoking the function. It only calls the function when I manually click the checkbox.

Comment: No still does not seem to have any effect with PHP selection.

Comment: This now seems to work with PHP selection but it now fails when I manually click on the checkboxes- total opposite of what was happening with my initial code. To resolve this, if I keep my original function plus keep `onclick=...` and also include your above code, it works perfectly but this will then add redundant codes in the page.

Comment: Yes I think so. I've updated the answer above with what has worked for me. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want function to be executed after page load, and also be axecuted every time checkbox state is changed you should do it this way:

```
<?php if (isset($mod['display']) && ($mod['display'] == "1")) { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } ?>
```

and in script:

```
function checkbox_click(current) {
  if($(current).is(':checked')) {
          // do stuff....
  } else {
          // do stuff....
  }
}

$(function(){
   $('.display_checkbox').each(function(){
      checkbox_click($(this));
   });
});
```

Also, I wouldn't do it that way. in this case, you should use onchange event binding.

Optimal solution i think would be:

```
<input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" <?php if (isset($mod['display']) && ($mod['display'] == "1")) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> />
```

and javascript should look like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.display_checkbox').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          // do stuff....
      } else {
          // do stuff....
      }
   });

   $('.display_checkbox').each(function(){
      $(this).change();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if (isset($mod['display']) && ($mod['display'] == "1")) { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox selectedcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <input class="display_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row; ?>][display]" value="1" onclick="checkbox_click(this);" />
<?php } ?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var obj = $(".selectedcheckbox");
   var found = obj.length;
   if(found == 1)
   {
     checkbox_click(obj);
   }
});

function checkbox_click(current) {
  if($(current).is(':checked')) {
      // do stuff....
  } else {
      // do stuff....
  }
}
```